# Cбор статистики загрузка процессора и памяти

Tags: windows, администрирование

Как собрать статистику по загрузке процессора и памяти процессами за промежуток времени, в файл?

Comment: счетчики производительности смотрели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На [superuser](http://superuser.com) упоминаются проги `tasklist` и `pslist`. Первая - из стандартного набора ОС, вторая - из `SysInternals tools` Марка Русиновича:

https://superuser.com/q/18830/505198

https://superuser.com/q/1061717/505198

Гуглил по фразе `ps aux для windows`.